# Multiple relationship between 2 tables

Tags: sql, database-design

Is it possibile to project database as in the picture below?
My problem is that:
User can belongs to many groups and grous can have many user
And
User can create many groups and one group belongs to one user
[image]

Comment: Yes, in a relational database there's no problem having 100 different relationships between two tables, if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible to implement.

Basically you do exactly what you've drawn in your picture. Both, users and groups have their ID (primary key) and assignments are implemented with a relation table (combined key with foreign keys UserID and GroupID). And in addition you'll have a field in the group table e.g. 'Owner' which is a foreign key to the UserID field.

```
User (**UserID**, Name)
Group (**GroupID**, Name, *OwnerID*)
rel_User_Group (*UserID*, *GroupID*)
```